# Spring WebFlux + Security - do we have the "remember-me" feature?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, java-8, spring-webflux

When I develop a non-reactive application and use rememberMe feature in authentication, I just extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class and overriding `configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity)` method. In that case, I have a rememberMe() method in a httpSecurity object.

But there is a difference when I use Spring WebFlux. As far as I know, all I have to do is defining a SecurityWebFilterChain bean using the instance of ServerHttpSecurity class, by invoking chain like:

```
serverHttpSecurity.authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .build();
```

But there is no method to handle rememberMe cookie here like in the HttpSecurity object where I could handle it in that way:

```
httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .rememberMe()
```

Do you know any solution?

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems impossible to do this.

There is an old [issue on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5504) and unfortunately, it is not known when it is going to be solved.

The comments recommend using a longer session expiration and offloading the sessions into an external data store (i.e. Redis). This way, you can store information in a database instead of in cookies.

They recommend using the Spring Session project.

Comment: I am using JWT and dont want to use external session storage like redis or any other storage. So Spring session is not an option for me.

Comment: Maybe here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603801/handling-expiry-remember-me-functionality-with-jwt there is an answer to your question, i.e. perhaps you should make infinite sessions together with jwt and implement the algorithm described by the link.

Answer (score 0):

The comments say that using a longer session expiration and offloading the sessions into an external data store (i.e. Redis). This way, you can store information in a database instead of in cookies.

They say use the Spring Session project.

Comment: Not sure this is an answer